# Datalist Input: Click to Add, Not Replace

Tags: javascript, input, datalist

I have been researching this but I can't seem to find search terms that fit the criteria.

I want a datalist text input (preferably still retaining autocomplete), but when a user clicks an item from the list, I want it to be added to the input, rather than replacing the entire contents of the input.

For example, I have a list of building locations including "back door", "front door", "first floor", "second floor", etc. The user should be able to click "first floor" from the list, and then "first floor" which results in the input having the value "first floor front door". I can think of a few ways to implement this, but I do not know how to expose the javascript for datalists, if that's even possible.

EDIT: Vanilla datalist: https://jsfiddle.net/h7gwjrm2/

```
<input list="data-list" placeholder="Double Click for List...">

<datalist id="data-list">
  <option>First Floor</option>
  <option>Second Floor</option>
  <option>Back Door</option>
  <option>Front Door</option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: Have you made enough of a start to have any of your [mcve] code ready in order that we can reproduce your starting point?

Comment: The thing is, I'm not even sure where to start. Making a vanilla datalist is trival, so I didn't bother including that, as well.

Comment: @Rune I've been working in the field for over four years now and I still have no idea, man. Flexdatalist (my own answer) solved the problem at the time, but these days I would have just manually programmed it with JavaScript).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging around for a couple hours, I think I finally found something that'll do the trick. Flexdatalist has an option for multiple items for the same input. Thanks everyone who took at look at my question, anyhow.

http://projects.sergiodinislopes.pt/flexdatalist/

Answer (score -1):

How to add to a result instead of replace. This should get you started. Next time post what you tried first so we have a better idea.

```js
let locations = ["back door", "front door", "first floor", "second floor"];
let result = "";
for (let i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  result += locations[i] + " ";
}
alert(result);
```

Comment: That's not what I meant. I meant being able to select multiple items from a datalist input. I added a jsfiddle for a plain one, which only selects one from a list.